# Python calling method from super class via child class not working as expected

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, pygame, duck-typing

I have extended `pygame.Rect` with my `Ball` class. When I use `nstanceOfBall.colliderect()` (line 66), no errors are thrown, yet it never returns true.  Any insight into why `colliderect` isn't working for my Ball instances?

```
    import sys, pygame
    import os
    import ball
    import random
    import math
    #from ball import Ball

    ###############################################################################################

    class Ball(pygame.Rect):
        def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, screenWidth, screenHeight):
            super(pygame.Rect,self).__init__(x, y, width, height)
            self.floatX=x
            self.floatY=x
            self.screenWidth=screenWidth
            self.screenHeight=screenHeight
            self.speed=[random.random()*5-2.5, random.random()*5-2.5]

        def runLogic(self):
            self.floatX+=self.speed[0]
            self.floatY+=self.speed[1]

            if self.floatX+16<0: self.floatX=self.screenWidth
            if self.floatX>self.screenWidth: self.floatX=-16
            if self.floatY+16<0: self.floatY=self.screenHeight
            if self.floatY>self.screenHeight: self.floatY=-16

            self.x=self.floatX
            self.y=self.floatY

    ###############################################################################################

    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (700, 200)#1680,1440)

    pygame.init()

    size = width, height = 320, 240
    white = 255, 255, 255
    blue=0,0,255

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
    ballRect=image.get_rect()
    balls = []

    for x in range(0, 100):
        balls.append(Ball(random.random()*width, random.random()*height, ballRect.width, ballRect.height, width, height))

    lastFrameStartTime=pygame.time.get_ticks()

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()

        for ball in balls:
            ball.runLogic()

            for ball2 in balls:
                if ball != ball2:                
                    if ball.colliderect(ball2):
                        print("collision detected!")
                        balls.pop(balls.index(ball))
                        balls.pop(balls.index(ball2))
                        #balls.remove(ball2)

        screen.fill(blue)
        for ball in balls:
            screen.blit(image, ball)
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.wait(33-(pygame.time.get_ticks()-lastFrameStartTime))
        lastFrameStartTime=pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Using super(Ball, self) instead of super(pygame.Rect, self) in Ball.init did the trick.

Thank you.

Comment: In `Ball.__init__`, you should call `super(Ball, self)` instead of `super(pygame.Rect, self)`. See the [documentation on super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.  ballInstance.colliderect is not behaving as desired.

Comment: @NCao You should make that the answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first arument to `super` must be the current class, i.e. `Ball` instead of `pygame.Rect`:

```
class Ball(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, screenWidth, screenHeight):
        super(Ball, self).__init__(x, y, width, height)
        ...
```

There is an example in the [documentation on super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

The point of `super` is that it allows you to call the next method in the inheritance order without requiring you to refer to the parent class explicitly. This comes handy when using multiple inheritance, see e.g. [super confusing python multiple inheritance super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354786/super-confusing-python-multiple-inheritance-super)