# Why does a classmethod's super need a second argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-2.x, class-method

This works as expected:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   @classmethod
...   def hello(cls):
...     print 'hello, foo'
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   @classmethod
...   def hello(cls):
...     print 'hello, bar'
...     super(Bar, cls).hello()
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.hello()
hello, bar
hello, foo
```

I can also call the base class explicitly:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   @classmethod
...   def hello(cls):
...     print 'hello, bar'
...     Foo.hello()
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.hello()
hello, bar
hello, foo
```

I was wondering why I can't omit the first argument to `super`, like this:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   @classmethod
...   def hello(cls):
...     print 'hello, bar'
...     super(Bar).hello()
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.hello()
hello, bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in hello
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

when the result of the `super` call without a second argument seems to be a class type inside a super type:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   @classmethod
...   def hello(cls):
...     print Foo, type(Foo)
...     print super(Bar), type(super(Bar))
...     print cls, type(cls)
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.hello()
<class '__main__.Foo'> <type 'type'>
<super: <class 'Bar'>, NULL> <type 'super'>
<class '__main__.Bar'> <type 'type'>
```

I guess I'm just wondering about the design here. Why would I need to pass the class object into the super call to get a reference to the base class type `Foo`? For a normal method, it makes sense to pass `self` to the function, since it needs to bind the base class type to an actual instance of the class. But a classmethod doesn't need a specific instance of the class.

**EDIT**:
I get the same error in Python 3.2 as I do above in 2.7 for `super(Bar).hello()`. However, I can simply do `super().hello()` and that works fine.

Comment: In python 3.x they fix super calls quite a bit ... in python2x they just didnt think it through that much (is my guess...) anyway I think this is going to end up closed as "Why" questions usually are...

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354786/super-confusing-python-multiple-inheritance-super?rq=1

Comment: @JoranBeasley meh, I've asked several why-type questions before that have not been closed.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: For many such questions, when it comes to Python, the reasons are well documented making such questions perfectly answerable. Python 3 added a implicit `__class__` scoped variable so you can omit the arguments and `super()` will inspect the calling frame to grab both the type and the bind argument (`self` or `cls`).

Comment: @JoranBeasley for the record, same error in 3.x, just edited question

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah, you're right, `super().hello()` works in 3.x, but `super(Bar).hello()` gets the same error.

Comment: @jterrace: Because only the version *without* arguments will look in the surrounding scope for the type and object to bind to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`super()` returns a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and needs two items:

- A starting point from which to search the class hierarchy.
- The argument to *bind* the returned methods.

For the two argument (and implicit zero-argument <sup>*</sup>) case the second argument is used to bind to, but if you do not pass in a second argument, `super()` cannot invoke the descriptor protocol to bind the returned functions, classmethods, properties or other descriptors. `classmethods` are still descriptors and are bound; the bind to a class and not an instance, but `super()` *does not know* how the descriptor will use the context to which you bind.

`super()` should not and cannot know that you are looking up a class method instead of a regular method; class methods only differ from regular methods because their `.__get__()` method acts differently.

Why are class methods bound? Because when you subclass `Foo` but do **not** override `.hello()`, calling `Bar.hello()` invokes the `Foo.__dict__['hello']` function, binds it to `Bar` and your first argument to `hello(cls)` will be that subclass, not `Foo`.

Without a second argument, `super()` returns an unbound object that can manually be bound later on. You can do the binding yourself using the `.__get__()` method provided by the `super()` instance:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        print 'hello, bar'
        super(Bar).__get__(cls, None).hello()
```

`super().__get__()` on an instance without a context effectively returns a new `super()` instance with the context set. On an instance with a context `.__get__()` just returns `self`; it is already bound.

---

<sup>*</sup> In Python 3, calling `super()` without arguments from inside a bound method will use the calling frame to discover, implicitly, what the type and bound object are, so you no longer have to explicitly pass in the type and object arguments in that case. Python 3 actually adds a implicit `__class__` closure variable to methods for this purpose. See [PEP 3135](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) and [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic)